# how to apply 1 domain for more than 2 servers with specific destinations

Tags: apache, dns

I read this [2 years old post](https://serverfault.com/questions/347689/how-to-share-domain-name-with-multiple-servers) about sharing domain for 2 or more domains

I wondering if it is possible, and how to do it, to share 1 domain (www.domain.com) for 2 different servers and  filter in apache the request based on a regex or so.

ex.

1. user is browsing to www.domain.com
2. site is delivering images
3. if the image file is starting with a 'number' apache is requesting the content from server A
4. if the image file is starting with a 'letter' apache will request the content from server B

I do want to know if it possible to setup it mainly from DNS records without involving apache too much.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do so. You should create subdomain, pointing to different server in DNS, to divert traffic. Example: www.example.com serving images from static.example.com

Comment: I know how to use records for subdomain but in this case I'm looking for a different solution as described above.

Comment: If you reach server-side codes, forwarding will cause time, which inevitable results in slow loading time of your website